# Angular modal service to popover

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I am using Angular directive for modal box

Here is my markup:

```
 <li><a ng-attr-title="{{::'Share'}}" 
        href="" class="shareButton" bh-model-ctrl="ShareArticleCtrl" 
        bh-template-html="shareArticleTemplate.html" 
        bh-alternate-id="items.alternate_id" 
        bh-title="items.bookmark_title" bh-url="items.bookmark_url" 
        bh-share-article></a></li>
```

and directive code is like

```
app.directive("bhShareArticle", ["$modal", "$window", function ($modal, $window) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                alternateId: '=bhAlternateId',
                bookmarkTitle: '=bhTitle',
                bookmarkUrl: '=bhUrl'
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.click(function (event) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                        templateUrl: attrs.bhTemplateHtml,
                        controller: attrs.bhModelCtrl,
                        size: 'sm',
                        resolve: {
                            bookmark: function () {
                                return {
                                    alternateId: scope.alternateId,
                                    bookmarkTitle: scope.bookmarkTitle,
                                    bookmarkUrl: scope.bookmarkUrl
                                };
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    modalInstance.result.then(function () {
                        if (attrs.redirect == "true") {
                            $window.location.href = '/user/dashboard';
                        }
                    }, function () {
                    //$log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
                    });
                });

                scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                    element.off('click');
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Which is working fine. Now we want to change into **popover**.

Can we do easily ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover.
I think you just have to do your logic in your main controller.